# flask socket io private chat

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

How to send personal message in flask socket io?  I have a hint about request.sid but i don't know how can i get the request.sid of person whom i am sending message?  How can i assign a common room to sender and receiver?

```
if user_exist:
        @socketio.on('private message', namespace='/message/')
        def join(msg):
            join_room(request.sid)
            room = request.sid
            emit("my response",{ "data" : msg['data'] },room=room)
```

Here the request.sid refers the sid of sender not of receiver, so how can i assign both of them same room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of approaches to do this.

When each client connects you can associate the `request.sid` that was assigned to that client with your user information. For example, you can add it as an extra field in your user database. Then when you need to send a message to a single client, lookup the `sid` in your database, then pass it as the `room` argument in the `emit()` call.

Another, maybe simpler option is to put each client in a room of their own when they connect. For example, you can assign each client to a room that is named after the provided username. Then you can send a message to a user simply by passing `room=username` in the `emit()` call.

Comment: Hey Miguel, I guess the first approach is the perfect one which i can implement.